# Map polygon coordinates on image

Tags: php, jquery, maps, typo3

For a client I need to create a map (= image) with different polygon markers on it. It's an image of a small area with houses on it. My client wants to edit this themselves, so there has to be a way to map the polygons (4+ points) in a sort off visual editor (Google like 'My Maps').

I've searched for a couple off days on Google and on here, but I can not find any answer if this is even possible.

So my #1 question is, is this even possible or should I tell the client that its impossible to do something like this?

If question #1 == possible: question #2 is:
Does someone have some code, any tutorial or documentation to get me started? Prefferably complient with Typo3, not a must, but I should be able to parse the coordinates to PHP to save in MySQL.

Thanks in advance,

Jeroen

Comment: Do you want to create a Google maps marker (icon), an image, mark an areas of a map? examples would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For image maps, the extension "imagemap_wizard" has proven very useful to me.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the advise, it seems to get working, only thing I run into now is that I cant scale down the image and thus zoom in on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest 2 solutions to solve this:

1. If you're using templavoila, then you may create an FCE(Flexible
   Content Element) and implement image-map via typoscript as given in this
   link: 
   **https://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/typoscript-for-image-map/**.

   The rest need to be handled using javascript.
2. Use MW Imagemap extension: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/mwimagemap

Comment: The MW Imagemap is now migrated to imagemap_wizard like Jost said

Answer (score 0):

I am the programmer of MW Imagemap and I can tell you that MW Imagemap has definitely not migrated to imagemap_wizard.